# How to create a dummy Linked Server in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a database in two different production servers. I want to keep the schemas consistent between the two. One has jobs that call stored procedures that reference a Linked Server. The other does not (and should not) contain those jobs or a Linked Server of the same name as that in the first server, but I want both servers to have those same stored procedures. However, SQL Server refuses to create the procedures that reference the Linked Server on the server that has no Linked Server set up. I understand why that happens, but I need a workaround that does not involve changing the procedure code (such as to use Dynamic SQL to hide the reference from the compiler).

I tried creating a Linked Server of the expected name that points to the local server, but SQL Server is smart enough to see that the referenced tables do not exist on that Linked Server. If I create one to a non-existent server, SQL times out during the creation of the procedure saying that it couldn't connect to the remote server.

Is there any way to create a dummy Linked Server such that SQL Server will not try to validate the table names on the Linked Server?

Comment: Cant you use dynamic SQL ?

Comment: I can use dynamic SQL, but have no interest in modifying a large number of stored procedures in a stable code base to resolve this issue.

Comment: then @AaronBertrand has provided answer which you can implement with minimal code change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create dummy, empty tables on the local server so that the procedure creation can happen.
2. Change the procedure code to use two-part synonyms. On the server that needs to use the linked server:

   ```
   CREATE SYNONYM dbo.whatever FOR linkedserver.dbo.whatever;
   ```

   On the local server that doesn't need the remote references to exist:

   ```
   CREATE SYNONYM dbo.whatever FOR dbo.emptydummytable;
   ```

   The stored procedure using the latter can be created thanks to deferred name resolution (which doesn't work when creating a procedure that references a linked server). This will require changing the stored procedure code, but it will be a one-time change.

Comment: That still involves changing all the existing stored procedures, but certainly would be far less horrible than changing them to use dynamic SQL.

The Linked Server goes to an instance holding a database for a third-party system (which therefore has a very stable schema). How crazy would it be to just create an empty copy of that database on the local server that shouldn't link to the real Linked Server, and create a Linked Server of the expected name that points to that local copy? That would eliminate the need to modify any of the existing code.

Comment: I created a local copy of that remote database (with empty tables) and that resolved the issue. Luckily, the schema in that database is from a third-party application and is therefore stable. I'll just have to update the schema of my dummy local database should we go through a version upgrade of that application.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a linked server that goes nowhere

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'THISSERVERNAME', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI'
```

Then any queries notice that the linked server is there, but has no access to anything within it. you'll find quite often that the queries for linked servers(as far as I'm aware) just check for the linked server (since you're declaring it as not as SQL database it doesn't seem to check in as much detail it presumes you know what you're doing (If you do it in the GUI you will get an warning but can still create the linked server without it registering that it can connect.

Not sure if this is an acceptable workaround for what you're after since you are actually creating a linked server, but it is essentially a dummy as it goes nowhere, if you ever tried to access it you'd get a login error

Comment: From my original post: "If I create one to a non-existent server, SQL times out during the creation of the procedure saying that it couldn't connect to the remote server."

Comment: creating the procedure shouldn't alert you to there being a problem, running the procedure will cause a problem but the actual creation shouldn't i've just ran the following query on 2012: 
  create procedure test
  as
  select * from invalidserver.nullschema.nonexistenttable
and had no problem

Comment: @SteBov Try an actual 4-part name, like `invalidserver.invaliddb.nullschema.nonexistenttable`. Deferred name resolution works for local references (in the same database or in a different database on the same server), but not for linked server references. What you actually created was a reference to `invaliddb.nullschema.nonexistenttable`.

Comment: Before I created a local copy of that remote database (with empty tables), I couldn't successfully create procedures that referenced it. After creating that dummy local database, they worked fine. If your suggestion worked, I would never have had the problem in the first place. As Aaron mentioned in his recent comment, the difference is between the 3 part names in your example and the 4 part names used in my stored procedures.